# Error in model.frame.default(formula = humvar$labels ~ ., data = humvar.train, : variable lengths differ (found for 'DANN_score')

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree

I am a uni student starting to use R and have received this error message, any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(readxl)
library(party)
library(pROC)
library(tree)
library(dplyr)


humvar <- humvar_1_xid_3799399_2

nrow(humvar)   #all rows ()

humvar[sample(nrow(humvar)),]   #all rows - essentially shuffles the data

humvar <- humvar[sample(nrow(humvar)),]   #overwrite humvar

head(humvar)

bound <- nrow(humvar)*0.75     #all rows x 0.75 assigned to 'bound' (75%)

humvar.train <- humvar[1:bound,]  #rows 1-28,986 assigned to 'humvar.train'

humvar.test <- humvar[(bound+1):nrow(humvar),]   #rows  (25%)

prop.table(table(humvar.train$labels))  #verify if the randomisation is correct

prop.table(table(humvar.test$labels))

##classification decision tree (training)

fit <- rpart(humvar$labels~., data = humvar.train$labels, method = 'class')
```

The last line of code above produces this error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = humvar$labels ~ ., data = humvar.train,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'DANN_score')
```

Comment: That's an unusual way to do a train/test split. What if 75% of nrow() is not an integer? Does the bracket subsetting take fractional numbers (I don't know, never thought to try).

Comment: I see exactly what you mean, it's not something I can comment on as this is the first train/test split I've done and have absolutely no knowledge around the topic whatsoever!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your error without your data, but it seems you are referencing two different datasets (the full and the subsetted) in the last line of code, which should read:

```
rpart(labels~., data = humvar.train$labels, method = 'class')
```

(i.e., not `rpart(humvar$labels~.`, which references the outcome in the full data set.)

Building off of @Bill O'Brian's comment, I suggest you look into the `caTools::sample.split` for splitting into training and testing

i.e.

```
caTools::sample.split(data$outcome, SplitRatio = 0.75)
train <- subset(data, sample == TRUE)
test <- subset(data, sample == FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi there, that makes sense. I have added your correction and run the code:          fit <- rpart(labels~., data = humvar.train$labels, method = 'class')                               Which results in another error message which I can't make sense of:                 Error in model.frame.default(formula = labels ~ ., data = humvar.train$labels,  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list                                                            This method is one suggested by my lecturer in fact, however I will definitely look into this. Thank you.

Comment: Try converting the dataset to a data frame with data.frame(humvar.train)

Comment: Okay thank you. Should it look like this?:  fit <- rpart(labels~., data.frame(humvar.train) = humvar.train$labels, method = 'class')   If so, Im getting another confusing error message about the '=': Error: unexpected '=' in "fit <- rpart(labels~., data.frame(humvar.train) ="

Comment: Hi George, “data = data.frame(humble.train)” would likely work. Since you are new I want to help you continue to use this site. This forum provides targeted, specific answers to novel questions. It is clear you are learning R, which is great - but it is clear you don’t know how to use R to run this model (again, that’s fine, we all start somewhere). But this is not a tutoring website. I tell you this because you received several downvotes likely because of this (not by me), which eventually will get you banned. Just trying to help. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up JP, that's a shame. I'm sure you'll be glad to hear that I have worked around this using a slightly different model - yay.